# Reliable/Safety-critical JAVA middleware - Best practices

Tags: java, middleware

What are the best practices for implementing reliable and safety-critical Java middleware?

Comment: that's a really broad question... what do you want your middleware to do?

Comment: @Cogsy, I'm not sure how to answer you...in essence the middleware  reads data off remote sensors and this data is then used to make decisions to move mechanical parts of a machine

Answer (score 0):

The following properties come into my mind:

- You might use Real-time Java for time-critical operations
- Build fault tolerance and lots of retry into the communication if you have a proprietary protocol
- You might consider a SOAP provider with WS-Reliability extension for example.
- Have an industrial PC and hardware, not a desktop one.
- You might want to use watchdogs on both ends and for example stop/pause the mechanical movements